# Installed mysql but cannot login: Access denied for user 'xxxxxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql

Installed MySQL - but not able to login with the user I created. It gives me the following error.

```
Access denied for user 'xxxxxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you still login to MySQL with root?

Comment: How did you create the user? Is this user listed when you log in as root? Is this MySQL from regular Ubuntu packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is to login into mysql as a root user and grant privileges to other usernames.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

use the password, which you entered during the installation process.

```
grant all privileges on *.* to xxxxxxx@localhost identified by 'your_password_here' with grant option;
```

once this is done. You can login with your username using the command `mysql -p`